# java syntax question

Tags: java, android

Is this code instantiating a SectionedAdapter object and overriding getHeaderView in one line?

```
SectionedAdapter tagSectionedAdapter=new SectionedAdapter() {
    protected View getHeaderView(String caption, int index,
                                    View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView result=(TextView)convertView;

        if (convertView==null) {
            result=(TextView)getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.tag_listview_header, null);
        }

        result.setText(caption);

        return(result);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's declaring a class and overriding a method.

It's similar to declaring a class like this:

```
class MySectionedAdapter extends SectionedAdapter
{
   @Override
   protected View getHeaderView(...)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

And then instantiating that class:

`SectionedAdapter tagSectionedAdapter = new MySectionedAdapter();`

It's an anonymous inner class -- no name and a slightly different syntax.  It's used when you need only one specific instance of a class in certain situations.  For example, comparator classes are often implemented this way and passed into sort functions.

The class you implement can actually be an interface, not a class at all, as in the case of `Runnable`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're right. This is called an [anonymous inner class](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html). The class is defined but never given a name. (`SectionedAdapter` is actually the supertype  of the anonymous class.)